# How to display preview of a image

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc

I am browsing an image and was able to save it to database and also display the images from the database.

But I want to display the preview of the image before saving it to database. I am facing problem in previewing the image. Please suggest me any ideas on how to do this.

```
   //enter code here
    public ActionResult GetImage(int id)
    {
        //var Id == 1;
        var query = dbContext.Pictures.Where(i => i.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        {
            System.IO.MemoryStream outStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

            byte[] imageBytes = outStream.ToArray();

            if (query.Name != null)
            {
                byte[] image = query.Name;

                return File(image, "image/jpg");
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            } 
         }
     }
```

This is what I did for displaying the image in database. Its working for me, but how to preview the image in the view page before saving it to database?

Comment: What's the exact workflow? Is the image uploaded by the user? How/where/when do you want this preview to appear?

Comment: I think you need to explain in more detail what you want to accomplish. You want to show the image that you choose in the "browse file dialog"?

Comment: yes it is image uploaded by the user for saving it into databse.I need to preview the image in the view page before saving.

Comment: @thmsn yes i want to show the image that the user chooses from browse file dialog.i want to preview in the view itself before saving to database

Comment: show us the code, where are you facing problem?

Comment: @FahimParkar i edited my question with my code

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search for "html file upload preview" gave me the following pages

- http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2004/06/how_to_implemen.html
- [Html file upload preview by Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259754/html-file-upload-preview-by-javascript)

According to the other stackoverflow question there is some security problems in regards to getting the actual path of the image, else it would be easy to just display the same path in an image tag.

Comment: I tried the above links but it didnt worked for me,I need to store the path of the image file in a temporary location and later stream it in the client side for previewing, Any one please suggest me some idea